# Two to the three or two to the third?

Tags: phrase-usage, mathematics

I wonder if we can say "two to the three" to indicate 2 to the 3rd power.

Here are my attempts to search on Google for it:

[image]

And "two to the third" seems also OK:

[image]

Which one do you usually use?

Comment: If you Googled it in quotes (["two to the three"](https://www.google.com/search?q="two+to+the+three"&start=10)), you'd find significantly fewer results. Most of what I found was links to a song lyric, plus one link to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to express your phrase:

1. Two to the third power.
2. Two to the third.
3. Two to the power three.

Comment: Also, "two cubed."

Answer (score 0):

I would always describe that in words as

> 2 to the 3rd (power)

or

> 2 cubed.

I would never say

> Two to the Three

although I might say

> Two to the power of three.

And as a person who majored in physics in college, and has been a software developer for several decades, I have had occasion to discuss raising number to powers many many times. I have never heard a native speaker who knows math say "Two to the three". When the exponent is not a whole number and does not nicely form an ordinal (like first, second, third, fourth) I would say

> Two to the power of four point three

or

> E to the X

or

> E to the power of X